# Encoding of 64-bit double

Tags: encodings, usb, float

I'm in the process of reverse engineering a USB driver, and I'm having problems finding a way to decode the binary representation of double values. The values don't seem to be encoded in IEEE-754 format.

Do you have any suggestions on how these values should be decoded? Below, I included a couple of example double values and their corresponding binary representation.

Thanks for your help!

```
1.0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
2.0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
3.0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
4.0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
5.0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 

-1.0: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
-2.0: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
-3.0: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
-4.0: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 
-5.0: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 

-0.1: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1010 
-1.1: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1010 
-2.2: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0111 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0100 
-3.3: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0010 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1101 
-4.4: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0111 
-5.5: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

1.1: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 
1.2: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 
1.3: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 
1.4: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 
1.5: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
1.6: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 0110 
1.7: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 
1.8: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 
1.9: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 

-9999.0: 1111 1111 0110 0011 1100 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a fixed-point (rather than a floating-point) format.

If you treat the 64-bit values as signed integers and divide by 4398046511104.0, you will get the decimal values you show.

e.g. the following will print -9999

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int64_t x = 0xFF63C40000000000LL;

    double y = x / 4398046511104.0;

    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```